# How to change the name shown in my PC when I connect my phone in MTP mode?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, mtp

When I connect my phone ( actually a 7' inch tablet ) to my PC and set the mode to be MTP, in my PC it shows GEM703L from where I can access Internal Storage and SD card, but the problem is that my phone is actually GEM701L and as I want to sell my phone it sounds awkward. Does the problem have anything to do with cust? How can I fix it?

P.S : I know that I can rename the name in Windows Explorer but that doesn't change the name permanently and the name changes as I connect the phone to some other PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the file `/system/build.prop`

Change the `ro.product.model` or `ro.product.device` or any other property that has your device name and reboot..

Note:
I think you need to uninstall your device drivers from your computer after doing that..

Ofcourse, this requires root access (yeah, no official OTAs), and also make sure to backup your build.prop